# symfony functional tests webtestcase doesn't work

Tags: symfony, testing, phpunit

I try to write a functional test for my app but I am getting following error:

```
InvalidArgumentException: The option "test_case" must be set.
```

I tried googling for it but found literally no clues.

My code:

```
class WhateverTest extends WebTestCase {
    public function testWhatever() {
        $client = static::createClient();
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/home');
        $this->assertEquals(1, 1);
    }
```

in phpunit.xml the kernel is set

```
<php>
    <server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="app/" />
</php>
```

My `AppKernel` has just two functions: `registerBundles()` and `registerContainerConfiguration`

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Check which `WebTestCase` class you are using. Most probably you are using

`use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Tests\Functional\WebTestCase`

and you should be using

`use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;`

So just change this one line and you should be good

Comment: Also another identically named class found here:   Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Tests\Functional\WebTestCase   
can be easily mistaken.

Comment: Can someone please explain what the difference between those classes is? As a newbie to symfony it's easy to use the wrong one and I can't find any explanation on why there are multiple ones with the same class name.

Answer (score 4):

you may have mistakenly used

```
    Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Tests\Functional
```

or

```
    Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Tests\Functional\WebTestCase
```

instead of

```
    Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase,
```